# Windows 7 Enterprise MAK needs Reactivation?

Tags: windows-7, licensing

I have a VMware image that contains our "standard workstation" where I do a lot of testing.

I used a Windows 7 Enterprise MAK key (from MSDN) for activation because the doc said that MAK keys don't have to be reactivated when the hardware changes.

Activation was done with

- slmgr.vbs /ipk LICENSE-KEY
- slmgr.vbs /ato

Now after some testing where the virtual hw was changed it says it "needs to activate because the hw has changed".

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. the MAK is a "normal" MAK - it allows multiple activations, but it also invalidates, like all activations, on hardware changes. At least this was my understanding from the start (can you provide a quote from the doc saying it does not need reactivation?).

That said, my experience with them is limited - I run a KMS because it is a lot easier.

Comment: I can't find the exact document but I guess I have a different understanding of the term 'perpetual' than Microsoft: "MAK activation is used for one-time perpetual activation with activation services that are hosted by Microsoft." Apparently perpetual does not mean forever. Thanks.

Comment: yes "1 time perpetual"  If you invalidate the activation then you have to get another "1 time perpetual" activation.  Like anything else perpetual, it exists until destroyed

Comment: perpetual means until deactivated (by hardware change). This is different from a KMS activaition which is valid only 6 months (and the server tries to renew every week). Basically the MAK version stays active until you change something, the KMS version gets regularly reactivated (locally by the KM Sserver).

Comment: Kind of like Duncan's an immortal unless he loses his head? :-)

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Just less bloody and without cool special effects ;)